# Is it a bad practise to assume that a ViewControllers dataSource takes a lot of time to return the results

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

My ViewController has a `dataSource`, which in my case has to fetch the data from a Webservice. Is it bad practise when I assume in my ViewController that the dataSource-methods will take quite long and only call them from another thread.

So I do the following:

1. Display a list of items
2. User touches a cell
3. The DetailViewController is shown instantly with the parent being its `dataSource`
4. The DetailViewController now

   - Displays a loading indicator
   - Asks the dataSource for the data in another Thread
   - Upon completion hides the indicator (called on the main thread)

Comment: Is it actually the true approach to handle data loader. But I'm curious how do manage Threads? Actually with latest additions NSThread is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I prefer that approach to some you usually see:

1. User Touches a cell
2. The current `UIViewController` asks the DataSource for data
3. The DataSource makes a request to the webservice.
4. On completion the new `UIViewController` is loaded with data.

Although, you might give a good experience to the user, if you put an spinner on the Cell or some kind of visual reference that shows that something is happening on the background. Either way, its sometimes a matter of taste, UX, or even client requisites.

> Is it bad practise when I assume in my ViewController that the
>   dataSource-methods will take quite long

[Murphy Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)... So it's a good practice to assume that and create the necessary mechanisms for when that happens.